# how i can insert chart head title in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a code the represent the chart for 3 coalmines. The chart is appeared correctly but head title of the chart not appeared.
the chart title iS "infected cases" how I can fix this problem?
the code is attached

```
Set r1 = Range(Cells(2, 26), Cells(Lastrow, 26))
Set r2 = Range(Cells(2, 32), Cells(Lastrow, 32))
Set r3 = Range(Cells(2, 33), Cells(Lastrow, 33))

Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Chart"
With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=100, Width:=375, Top:=75, Height:=225)
.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Union(r1, r2, r3)
.ChartTitle.Text = "infected cases"
.Chart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
End With
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart.hastitle - Is this property set to True?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, please:

```
Sub chartTitle()
  Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range
  Set r1 = Range(cells(2, 26), cells(lastRow, 26))
  Set r2 = Range(cells(2, 32), cells(lastRow, 32))
  Set r3 = Range(cells(2, 33), cells(lastRow, 33))

  Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.count)
  ActiveSheet.Name = "Chart"
  With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(left:=100, width:=375, top:=75, height:=225).Chart
    .SetSourceData Source:=Union(r1, r2, r3)
    .HasTitle = True  'necessary line to accept a title!
    .ChartTitle.Text = "infected cases"
    .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
  End With
End Sub
```